# Is there an alternative to Shazam, but for OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation, shazam

As you probably already know, [Shazam](http://shazam.com) is a music identification service. However, it is only available on mobile platforms. Is there an alternative to Shazam, but for OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is [Tunatic](http://www.wildbits.com/tunatic/). It has a handy little window with a sound visualizer:

[image: Tunatic]
[image: Identifying song...]
Once it identifies the song, it displays the name and artist:
[image: Tunatic found song]
And takes you to a link where you can download it from iTunes or buy the ringtone version:
[image: Tunatic link]

Comment: Shame is it so fugly. Did you ever find anything else?

Comment: @codecowboy sadly, no…that's all I've found, even now

Comment: hmmm... is there an opportunity here?

Answer (score 2):

Since your question stem from the fact that Shazam was only available on mobile platforms, today would be best to answer with [this link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shazam/id897118787?l=fr&mt=12) and the news that Shazam has a desktop version for Mac OSX as well.

Comment: yeah but it doesn't work like mobile shazam, like "start recording for 20 seconds and identify" feature

Comment: @LolaRun It is true that the method is different. The idea of the destop app is that you turn it on and then it listens and registers song identified by it. If you also hate the idea of a program constantly "listening in" into your life (as I do) you can turn it on only when you need it. It will still identify the song playing in about 20 secs. So practically you can use the same way you might use its mobile brother. If you have problems on Mac you might want to check out its [Mac-specific knowledge base](https://support.shazam.com/hc/en-us/articles/204458078-Mac-app-not-getting-results).

Comment: yeah i tried it like so, and i also tried tunatic but both do not work if i'm listening through my earphones, because they don't read the in feed. the work on the microphone only, and i'm at work... anyway thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

http://www.wildbits.com/tunatic/
something like may work, but these are generally not too popular on an actual computer since your usually stationary and know the music being played (usually from your computer) so there is no need to know it, but if your on the laptop or playing a radio in the back round i can see the need. As far as the linked software i cannot speak for it as i have never tried it myself.